# Install with EFI, dual boot and manual partitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Installing ubuntu 18.04 and already have windows 10 installed. I tried installing before realising EFI would be a problem and had error: the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/

As for selecting my partitions during ubuntu installation, I'm not sure what to do for boot.

If I select the windows boot manager partition (EFI) it gives me an option to use it as a "EFI system partition" but does not ask me to select a mount point or anything else. Is that correct?

If I have the windows EFI partition should I still select my biosgrub partition to install the ubuntu boot loader onto? Or is that supposed to be installed onto the efi partition?

I am reading 'help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_EFI_System_Partition' but this does not make sense given what I can see on the 18.04 installer: "if you use the manual partitioning ("Something else"), the difference is that you will have to set the /boot/efi mount point to the UEFI partition"

Comment: i tried selecting efi in the install as efi and ignoring it. Both times i used a seperate boot partition. Both time I get the same error. :(

Comment: The bios-grub-partition is needed only if you install on a gpt-partitioned drive in legacy-mode. You want to install in UEFI-mode and you don't need this partition. Remind the following rule: how you boot the installer is how you install, e.g. if you boot the installer in UEFI-mode, Ubuntu will be installed in UEFI-mode

Comment: In my laptop  bios it says that only EFI boot is allowed, so i assume that I have booted in EFI mode. However, the ubuntu 18.04 installation still requests me to select a device for boot loader installation.

It defaults to /dev/dm-0. So there are two possibilities. 1. There's a bug in the installer or 2. It's intended that I choose /dev/dm-0 to install. I don't know? or... maybe i'm supposed to choose the efi partition.